# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wifi device not ready

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, internet

I have installed UBUNTU 16.04 LTS recently and when trying to connect wi-fi it shows no wi-fi connection at all and it says device not ready. I have tried so many methods available on the internet such as:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Also, open or create `/etc/pm/config.d/config` and add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"`, (replace `rtl8723be` with your own model number).

Then run `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and reboot

And so on, but they didnt work.

Anyway when I connected an ethernet cable, laptop got connected to the internet easily. So I assume the problem is with the wifi driver. Then I tried [this link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html), but didn't help.

I have a HP ENVY laptop with Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265, here are some outputs of the commands I executed:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 63
Region 0: Memory at c6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

For `iwconfig`:

```
iwconfig

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
```

For `lshw -c network`:

```
sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for wenuka: 
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 15
   serial: 30:8d:99:1a:91:a3
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.8.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:49 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6104000-c6104fff memory:c6100000-c6103fff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlp8s0
   version: 61
   serial: 5c:e0:c5:f5:6c:20
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=22.361476.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:63 memory:c6000000-c6001fff
```

It will be really helpful if someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just able to solve the issue and hope its better to post the solution rather than deleting the question.
The link (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323700) contains the answer. 
i.e. run

```
lsmod | grep acer
```

and there will be several entries appear in the console. If acer_wmi is in the output then enter,

```
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and then reboot.

Hope this helps somebody.