# Wifi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Alienware 17 R4

Tags: 14.04, alienware

Tried:

- Reinstalling the OS

  Restarting network-manager using `sudo service network-manager restart`

  Adding network controller to black list

  Removing network controller from black list

After restarting the network manager the wifi makes presence but it says
wifi hardware switch blocked.. I tried pressing the keyboard wifi key but it only turned off the bluetooth instead of the wifi.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could get your Alienware 17 working on Ubuntu:

1. Connect the machine to Internet using a LAN cable.
2. Change these after entering BIOS setup

   1. Set boot mode to Legacy
   2. Bring up the priority of the USB drive above hard disk in boot device list.
   3. Save and restart.
3. Install [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) from a USB stick.
4. After booting to newly installed Ubuntu –

   1. Install Wifi

      1. Open Terminal
      2. **sudo apt-get upgrade**
      3. yeah that’s it. Atheros Qualcomm Killer Wifi driver would now be installed.
      4. Restart the system, look for Wifi icon in status bar to verify.
   2. Install NVidia GeForce Graphics card driver

      1. Open Terminal
      2. **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa**
      3. **sudo apt-get update**
      4. **sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-settings**  ( nvidia-358 was the latest version when I installed. Please find the current version from [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) )
      5. Restart, verify if “GeForce GTX ** ” is shown as the Graphics card in “About This Computer” dialog.
   3. Fix issue with headphones not working –

      1. Open Terminal
      2. **alsamixer**
      3. Press F6
      4. Select “HDA Intel PCH” card
      5. Press right arrow till the Item shown is “HP/Speaker Auto Detect”
      6. Press M to set it on.
      7. Connect headphones and verify if it works.

Your Linuxed Alienware should now be up with sound, graphics and Wifi and Bluetooth working without issues.

References:

- http://www.codemarvels.com/2016/02/installing-ubuntu-on-alienware-17-r2/
- https://github.com/stormhart/dev-journal/wiki/Alienware-17-R4:-Dual-Boot-Windows-10---Ubuntu-16.04

Comment: The sudo apt-get upgrade did not work for the Wifi. The Wifi icon in status says "device not ready" under "Wi-Fi Networks".

Comment: That's another error message that you didn't mention before, in that case try with these existing solutions: [Wifi networks device not ready](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844746/wifi-networks-device-not-ready/862185) and [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wifi device not ready](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908878/ubuntu-16-04-lts-wifi-device-not-ready), good luck!