# Wireless not working on Ubuntu 16.04 for Alienware R5

Tags: networking, drivers, alienware

I have a new Alienware R5 laptop, and I'm trying to get the wireless to work on Ubuntu 16.04 (currently, only Ethernet works). How can I get wireless to work on this laptop?

Results of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:44:00.0
       logical name: enp68s0
       version: 10
       serial: e4:b9:7a:55:76:22
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=18.47.7.173 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:9dc00000-9dc3ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:45:00.0
       version: 29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:9db00000-9db03fff
```

Kernel information:

```
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I have tried solutions already posted, including using the solution in [Alienware 17 R4 Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016903/alienware-17-r4-ubuntu-16-04-wifi-driver), but it does not work for me unfortunately. When I run the final step `sudo make install`, I get the following result (and upon reboot, wifi does not work).

```
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/user/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/user/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/user/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/iwlxvt.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/user/backport-iwlwifi/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/user/backport-iwlwifi/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.15.0-43-generic
depmod will prefer updates/ over kernel/ -- OK!
Note:
You may or may not need to update your initramfs, you should if
any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs. To add
support for your distribution to do this automatically send a
patch against "update-initramfs.sh". If your distribution does not
require this send a patch with the '/usr/bin/lsb_release -i -s'
("Ubuntu") tag for your distribution to avoid this warning.

Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot.
```

New to Ubuntu, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I never resolved this for Ubuntu 16.04, but after following [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Alienware/comments/9wiwbo/i_have_achieved_linux_induced_bliss_with_my/), I installed Kubuntu 18.04 (with ethernet cable while installing third party drivers) and everything works beautifully now. Thankful for the original poster, sharing in case anyone else needs help.

Comment: We can't find out what is the wireless adapter. This Q&A are useless without this information. It means that some adapter didn't work, and know the unknown adapter works for some reason.